# Fallo al recuperar datos en BD Mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

**Hola a todos**; tengo un problema en mi proyecto.

A la hora de actualizar un registro en mi base de datos Mongo,
puedo guardar los datos actualizados, pero a la hora de recuperar los solo trae una palabra, si hay dos , **por ejemplo** *un nombre compuesto*, el segundo nombre no se trae de vuelta para poder actualizar el registro.

No se mucho sobre mongo pero se que las Bases de datos en caso de mandar 'hola mundo' me devolvería 'holamundo' o eso creo.
La pregunta es sí se puede guardar 2 palabras en un mismo registro de un campo separadas por un espacio o simplemente no se puede.
Y en caso de que se pueda que validación haría falta

Mil gracias y saludos

**EDICIÓN 1**

**Hola Sinay**, lo que estoy haciendo es coger los datos en un **req.body** y y igualarlos al usuario que se ha encontrado en la BD es así:

```
usuario.nombre = req.body.nombre;
```

Mi vista lo desplega asi:

```
<div class="campo">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input value= {{usuario.nombre}} type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre">
</div>
```

Y la validacion de express-validation seria:

```
 body('nombre').not().isEmpty().trim(['']).withMessage('El nombre es Obligatorio').escape(),

 body('nombre').isAlpha(['en-US','en-GB', 'es-ES']).withMessage('Solo letras para el nombre').escape(),
```

Espero que sea lo que querías, una saludo y gracias por tu interés

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Comment: Si el tipo de dato es "String" puedes guardar: "Texto con espacios";

Comment: Hola Alfonso, los datos yo diría que son un objeto , entonces los paso con , toString?     usuario.nombre = toString(req.body.nombre); . Seguro que esto es una barbaridad pero no tengo ni idea como implementarlo:))) . Si me puedes dar alguna pista de como hacerlo te lo agradeceria.Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código del back donde está el problema que tienes? Como actualizas y como obtienes los datos.

Comment: Kaixo Gudari; era cuestión de ponerlo entre comillas la variable en la vista "{{ }}" y así coje todo lo que hay en el campo. Eskerrik asko